# Delete repeating contents in the list of figures due to the use of '\ContinuedFloat'

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I want to generate list of figures. I used the command `\listoffigures`.
I have also used `\ContinuedFloat` as inserting the subfigures of a Figure was taking more than one page. The problem now is all the contents in the list of figures are printed twice as I used `\ContinuedFloat`. So how can I make the contents not to appear more than once? I have included a screen shot as well. Can someone please help?

The code which I have used is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}[singlelinecheck=false]
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\ \vrule\ } 

 \begin{document}

   \listoffigures
   \begin{figure}[H]
       \centering
       \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centerlast}
          \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub_1.jpeg}
            \caption[Short caption]{This is subfigure:1}
            \label{subfig1a}
          \end{subfigure} 
                \hfill
                \rulesep
          \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{sub_2.jpeg}
             \caption[Short caption]{This is subfigure:2}
             \label{subfig1b}
           \end{subfigure}
                  %
             \vspace{0.6cm}
             \hrule
             \vspace{0.6cm}\par
           \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
             \centering
             \includegraphics[width=0.79\linewidth]{sub_3.jpeg}
             \caption{This is subfigure:3}
             \label{subfig1c} 
           \end{subfigure}
         \caption{This is figure 3.}
         \label{fig1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[H] \ContinuedFloat
       \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=0.61\linewidth]{sub_4.jpeg}
         \caption{This is subfigure:4}
         \label{subfig4d}
       \end{subfigure}
       \caption{This is figure 1.}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your `MWE`?

Comment: Sure. I have posted my code.

Comment: Where is `\rulesep` defined?

Comment: That is not an MWE, there is no preamble, and we do not have access to you images (you can use `\rule{4cm}{4cm}` instead of the images, or just pass the `[demo]` option to `graphicx`

Comment: Use `\caption[]{This is figure 1.}` in the second part of the figure instead of `\caption{This is figure 1.}` The empty optional argument will prevent a second entry in the listoffigures.

Comment: where is `\listoffigures` ?

Comment: @leandriis Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\caption` with an ampty optional argument to suppress the second entry in the list of figures:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}[singlelinecheck=false]
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[H]
    \caption{This is the first part of the figure.}
     \label{fig3}
\end{figure}%


\begin{figure}[H] 
    \ContinuedFloat
    \caption[]{This is the second part of the figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```